# Expression Expected error in js for || variable

Tags: javascript

had a weird error message, Expression expected when i used ||

```
express = require("express");

const app = express();

const PORT = 3000; || process.env.PORT;
                 //right here
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`));
```

haven't tried much because i can't find any solutions, tried just restarting vsc

Comment: remove `;` after `3000`

Answer (score -1):

Remove `;` after `3000`

You accidentally put `;` before  `||`